# Extract string from text using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with URLs that are a dumped from the server, I have the task of matching certain patterns and extracting the IDs, I am not an expert in `RegExp` but have got a start.

Can you please look at the example below and let me know how best to take the IDs out, Thanks in advance

> ("`https://abcd.com/000001","Goods1`")

Here I need to take out **000001**

```
Function ExtractIds(urlstr As String)
    Dim reg
    Dim rng As Range, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim mtch, mt As String
    Set reg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With reg
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "/(.*?)"""
        .Global = False
    End With
    MsgBox reg.Test(tmpStr)
    If reg.Test(tmpStr) Then
        ExtractIds = reg.Execute(tmpStr)(0).SubMatches(0)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Is the pattern always like what you have mentioned? `https://abcd.com/` followed by the ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Public Function ExtractIds(urlstr As String)
   ary = Split(urlstr, "*")
   ExtractIds = ary(2)
End Function
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Based on your *Edit* use this instead:

```
Public Function ExtractIds(urlstr As String)
   Dim DQ As String
   DQ = Chr(34)
   ary = Split(urlstr, DQ)
   bry = Split(ary(1), "/")
   ExtractIds = bry(UBound(bry))
End Function
```

Comment: There was a typo in my post. ID is not surrounded by *. I have updated.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Awesome answer! Love the creative aspect of it and the simplicity.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I must say you are very much creative persion.